# Tutorials on connected data access architecture of ADO.Net?

Tags: ado.net

http://www.programmersheaven.com/2/FAQ-ADONET
Disconnected architecture is not well suited for desktop clients with multiple updates but most tutorials are oriented towards disconnected ado.net would like to see tuts on connected data access architecture.

So any links ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've written an ADO.NET tutorial that discusses connected operations:

http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorials/AdoDotNet/Lesson01.aspx

Joe